# numpy array with mpz/mpfr values

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, gmp

I want to have a numpy array with mpz/mpfr values. Because my code:

```
import numpy as np
import gmpy2
A=np.ones((5,5));
print A/gmpy2.mpfr(1);
```

generates:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  print A/gmpy2.mpfr(1);
[[1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]]
```

Which as I can understand is the impossibility to convert gmpy mpfr to numpy float64. So how can I get a numpy array with mpfr values in the first place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create your array with `dtype=object`, and then you can use any python type inside your array. I don't have gmpy2 installed, but the following example should show how it works:

```
In [3]: a = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=object)

In [5]: import fractions

In [6]: a *= fractions.Fraction(3, 4)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4],
       [3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4],
       [3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4],
       [3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4],
       [3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4, 3/4]], dtype=object)
```

Having a numpy array of `dtype=object` can be a liitle misleading, because the powerful numpy machinery that makes operations with the standard dtypes super fast, is now taken care of by the default object's python operators, which means that the speed will not be there anymore:

```
In [12]: b = np.ones((5, 5)) * 0.75

In [13]: %timeit np.sum(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit np.sum(b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.9 us per loop
```

Comment: Then again, `fractions.Fraction` is not an especially fast class. I wonder what the speed delta between native Numpy arrays and an `mpfr` array, seeing as `mpfr` is a relatively low-level C wrapper class.

Comment: @nneonneo I believe the problem is not that much the speed of the operations, but the fact that there are Python function calls involved in every single one of them, something that doesn't happen with the other numpy dtypes.

Comment: Yes, there are Python function calls, but for a class implemented in C, the overhead of these calls might be pretty small. `Fraction` is implemented in pure Python so each call is many bytecode instructions.

Comment: @nneonneo I just repeated the timings with an array of numpy floats and another one of dtype object, so of Python floats, and you do have a point. For a `(5, 5)` array, the performance differences are less than 5%, although numpy comes ahead. But with a `(500, 500)` array numpy is over 25x faster.

Comment: If you were using `=` instead of `*=`, you would not need to specify `dtype`. The issue is probably a problem in one of the two libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in one of the two libraries. I also believe it is fixed.

Input:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import gmpy2

print(sys.version)
print(np.__version__)
print(gmpy2.version)

A=np.ones((5,5));
print(A/gmpy2.mpfr(1))
```

Output:

```
3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
1.9.1
2.0.5
[[mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0')]
 [mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0')]
 [mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0')]
 [mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0')]
 [mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0') mpfr('1.0')]]
```

Either Numpy didn't properly say what to do when it encountered an unknown type, or gmpy2 didn't specify how to get divided by something ([`__rdiv__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rdiv__)).

It is not necessary to specify the `dtype` of an `ndarray` unless you intend to write over its elements. Operations like multiplication will result in a new `ndarray`, and Numpy will figure out what `dtype` to use.