# Efficient multiple precision numerical arrays

Tags: python, numpy, mpmath, gmpy

Numpy is a library for efficient numerical arrays.

mpmath, when backed by gmpy, is a library for efficient multiprecision numbers.

How do I put them together efficiently? Or is it already efficient to just use a Numpy array with mpmath numbers?

It doesn't make sense to ask for "as efficient as native floats", but you can ask for it to be close to the efficiency of equivalent C code (or, failing that, Java/C# code). In particular, an efficient array of multi-precision numbers would mean that you can do vectorized operations and not have to look up, say, `__add__` a million times in the Global Interpreter.

Edit: To the close voter: My question is about an *efficient* way of putting them together. The answer in the possible duplicate specifically points out that the naive approach is not efficient.

> Having a numpy array of dtype=object can be a liitle misleading, because the powerful numpy machinery that makes operations with the standard dtypes super fast, is now taken care of by the default object's python operators, which means that the speed will not be there anymore

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307589/numpy-array-with-mpz-mpfr-values

Comment: @cel Related, but not relevant. My question is about efficiency, while the answer mentions the inefficiency of doing it _that_ way.

Comment: It's more closely related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26600471/1461210

Comment: @ali_m That's another example of what not to do, while this question asks what to do.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I wasn't suggesting that your question was a duplicate - I just think it's useful to link to other related questions on SO for the benefit of other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`. The following tests were performed with the development version.

`a` and `b` are 1000 element lists containing pseudo-random `gmpy2.mpfr` values with 250 bits of of precision. The test performs element-wise multiplication of the two lists.

The first test uses a list comprehension:

```
%timeit [x*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 322 µs per loop
```

The second test uses the `map` function to perform the looping:

```
%timeit list(map(gmpy2.mul, a, b))
1000 loops, best of 3: 299 µs per loop
```

The third test is a C implementation of the list comprehension:

```
%timeit vector2(a,b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 243 µs per loop
```

In the third attempt, `vector2` tries to be a well-behaved Python function. Numeric types are handled using `gmpy2`'s type conversion rules, error-checking is done, etc. The context settings are checked, subnormal numbers are created if requested, exceptions are raised if needed, etc. If you ignore all the Python enhancements and assume all the value are already `gmpy2.mpfr`, I was able to get the time down on the fourth attempt:

```
%timeit vector2(a,b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 200 µs per loop
```

The fourth version doesn't do enough error checking to be of general use but a version between the third and fourth attempts may be possible.

It is possible to decrease Python overhead, but as the precision increases, the effective savings decreases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no existing Python library that supports vectorized array operations on multiple precision values. There's unfortunately no particularly efficient way to use multiple precision values within a numpy ndarray, and it's extremely unlikely that there ever will be, since multiple precision values are incompatible with numpy's basic array model.

Each element in a floating point numpy ndarray takes up the same number of bytes, so the array can be represented in terms of the memory address of the first element, the dimensions, and a regular byte offset (or stride) between consecutive array elements.

This scheme has significant performance benefits - adjacent array elements are located at adjacent memory addresses, so sequential reads/writes to an array benefit from better locality of reference. Striding is also very important for usability, since it allows you to do things like operating on views of the same array without creating new copies in memory. When you do `x[::2]`, you are really just doubling the stride over the first axis of the array, such that you address every other element.

By contrast, an array containing multiple precision values would have to contain elements of unequal size, since higher precision values would take up more bytes than low-precision values. A multiple precision array therefore cannot be regularly strided, and loses out on the benefits mentioned above.

In addition to the problems with constructing arrays, even plain arithmetic on multiple precision scalars is likely to be much slower than for floating point scalars. Almost all modern processors have specialized floating point units, whereas multiple precision arithmetic must be implemented in software rather than hardware.

I suspect that these performance issues might be a big part of the reason why there isn't already a Python library that provides the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for "as efficient as native floats", but you can ask for it to be close to the efficiency of equivalent C code (or, failing that, Java/C# code). In particular, an efficient array of multi-precision numbers would mean that you can do vectorized operations and not have to look up, say, `__add__` a million times in the Global Interpreter.

Comment: Sure, I'm certainly not suggesting that it's impossible to do any better than the current situation where GMP scalars are individually wrapped in Python.  In your question you specifically mentioned combining numpy and gmpy as a way to improve performance, so my answer was mainly aimed at explaining why I think that's unlikely to work.

Comment: My question was specifically about how to do better than naively combining Numpy and gmpy (i.e. having Numpy treat them as just ordinary Python objects). Another way to say it: What's the most efficient way to combine them?

Comment: Unfortunately there just *isn't* a more efficient way to combine numpy and gmpy than using an `np.object` array (essentially treating gmpy scalars as individual Python objects). To do better with numpy, it would be necessary to design a completely new type of array container (think `scipy.sparse` matrices vs `np.ndarray`). You haven't really described what your use-case is, but perhaps your best option might be to write your own extension in C/C++/Cython, calling the GMP library functions directly.

Comment: I maintain `gmpy2`. I have looked at adding vectorized versions of some of the `gmpy2` functions. I compared a list comprehension using `gmpy2.sin`, `map(sin, list)`, and `gmpy2.sin(list)` and there wasn't much difference (around 10%). I have not tried using `nd.array` or basic multiplication / addition functions. If you want to look at test code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A current project is [qd](https://github.com/baruchel/qd) which will be able to embed high-precision numbers in Numpy arrays by taking benefit of the fixed-size in memory of its values. Right now, the type is available for Numpy but not yet as a dtype; you can already use it with an object dtype however.

*(If you want to see what the dtype will look like, you may already uncomment the relevant line for compiling it with the Numpy support; it should work for having a glance but no function has been implemented yet; next release should be in september or october.)*